# Output probability of prediction in tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have a model.json generated from tensorflow via tensorflow.js coverter

In the original implementation of model in tensorflow in python, it is built like this:

```
model = models.Sequential([
        base_model,
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(num_classes)
    ])
```

In tensorflow, the probability can be generated by score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0]), according to the tutorial on official website.

How do I get this probability in tensorflow.js?

I have copied the codes template as below:

```
$("#predict-button").click(async function () {
    if (!modelLoaded) { alert("The model must be loaded first"); return; }
    if (!imageLoaded) { alert("Please select an image first"); return; }
    
    let image = $('#selected-image').get(0);
    
    // Pre-process the image
    console.log( "Loading image..." );
    let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(image, 3)
        .resizeNearestNeighbor([224, 224]) // change the image size
        .expandDims()
        .toFloat()
        // RGB -> BGR
    let predictions = await model.predict(tensor).data();
    console.log(predictions);
    let top5 = Array.from(predictions)
        .map(function (p, i) { // this is Array.map
            return {
                probability: p,
                className: TARGET_CLASSES[i] // we are selecting the value from the obj
            };
        }).sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.probability - a.probability;
        }).slice(0, 2);
        console.log(top5);
    $("#prediction-list").empty();
    top5.forEach(function (p) {
        $("#prediction-list").append(`<li>${p.className}: ${p.probability.toFixed(6)}</li>`);
        });
```

How should I modify the above code?

The output is just the same as the value of variable 'predictions':

```
Float32Array(5)
0: -2.5525975227355957
1: 7.398464679718018
2: -3.252196788787842
3: 4.710395812988281
4: -4.636396408081055
buffer: (...)
byteLength: (...)
byteOffset: (...)
length: (...)
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): (...)
__proto__: TypedArray


0: {probability: 7.398464679718018, className: "Sunflower"}
1: {probability: 4.710395812988281, className: "Rose"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Please help!!!
Thanks!

Comment: Isn't `p.probability.toFixed(6)` the probability?

Comment: It just output the values from the variable "predictions"

Comment: Include the output of predictions in the question.

Comment: It's now included in the edited question. The probability is simply just the same as the output value from the prediction.

Comment: I do not understand aren't those the probabilities you want?

Comment: Obviously these values are NOT probabilities (as they don't add up to 100%). They are just the activation values generated to the output nodes

Comment: In tensorflow, the real probabilities can be generated from tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to extract the probabilities from the logits of the model using a softmax function you can do the following:

This is the array of logits that are also the `predictions` you get from the model

```
const logits = [-2.5525975227355957, 7.398464679718018, -3.252196788787842, 4.710395812988281, -4.636396408081055]
```

You can call `tf.softmax()` on the array of values

```
const probabilities = tf.softmax(logits)
```

Result:

```
[0.0000446, 0.9362511, 0.0000222, 0.0636765, 0.0000056]
```

Then if you wanted to get the index with the highest probability you can make use of `tf.argMax()`:

```
const results = tf.argMax(probabilities).dataSync()[0]
```

Result:

```
1
```

#### Edit

I am not too familiar with jQuery so this might not be correct. But here is how I would get the probabilities of the outputs in descending order:

```
let probabilities = tf.softmax(predictions).dataSync();
$("#prediction-list").empty();
probabilities.forEach(function(p, i) {
  $("#prediction-list").append(
    `<li>${TARGET_CLASSES[i]}: ${p.toFixed(6)}</li>`
  );
});
```

Comment: That sounds great! So can you show me directly how I should modify the original code to display (not in console.log) the probabilities of each output in descending order? (I'm sorry, I am just the beginner of javascript when I want to publish my model online)

Comment: @Maximus could you check the updated answer?

Comment: @Maximus also why do you want to sort the probabilities?

Comment: There is an error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: probabilities.map is not a function"

Comment: Actually I don't need to sort the probabilities. Perhaps to simply the problem, I just want to output the probabilities for each class. Would that be more simple to amend the code? Thanks!

Comment: @Maximus could you include `console.log(probabilities)`? Yes also sorting it not needed at all for this.

Comment: t
dataId: {}
dtype: "float32"
id: 916
isDisposedInternal: false
kept: false
rankType: "1"
scopeId: 1472
shape: [5]
size: 5
strides: []
isDisposed: (...)
rank: (...)
__proto__: Object

Comment: console.log(probabilities) outputs the above; Seems there is no probabilities outputed

Comment: No there are values as it has a shape of 5. Could you try `probabilities.print()`?

Comment: probabilties.print() can print out the probabilties: Tensor
    [0.0000057, 0.607668, 0.3876045, 0.0033324, 0.0013894],
 but console.log(probabilities) cannot

Comment: The new code has this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: probabilities.forEach is not a function

Comment: How about now? I think the issue was that I was not downloading the tensors using `dataSync()`.